# error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, collections

I have an package delivery application and I am getting an error in my code below:

```
public class DeliveryDriver
{
    public List<int> DriverID { get; set; }
    public List<string> DriverName { get; set; }
}

var IDeliveryDriver = new List<DeliveryDriver>();

foreach (DataRow dr in dsDriverID.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    IDeliveryDriver.Add(new DeliveryDriver
    {
        DriverID = (List<int>)dr["DriverId"],
        DriverName = (List<string>)dr["DriverName"]
    });
}
```

The error occurs at the `IDeliveryDriver.Add` line and it goes into a catch block. The error is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'

What is causing the error?

Comment: 5 is not a list. It's a 5.

Comment: Is DriverID of a DeliveryDriver really supposed to be a `List<int>`? Like the error says, you can't cast dr["DriverId"] as a `List<int>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says it all - the `DriverId` field in each row is an `int`, not a `List<int>`. Ditto for `DriverName` being a `string`, not a `List<string>`. You should change your `DriverId` and `DriverName` properties to be `int` and `string` respectively, then cast to the right type too:

```
public class DeliveryDriver
{
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
}

...

foreach (DataRow dr in dsDriverID.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    IDeliveryDriver.Add(new DeliveryDriver
    {
        DriverID = (int) dr["DriverId"],
        DriverName = (string) dr["DriverName"]
    });
}
```

After all, each delivery driver does only have one name and one ID, don't they?